# Any way to specify a non-returned value for an RKEntityMapping?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, restkit

Because I am working with a non-KVC REST service I have a need to designate a `bool` attribute `isSpecial` by the request URL rather than by any of the returned JSON. For instance, if I make the request `http://www.service.com/GetObject?isSpecial=no` then I would like to specify that the attribute `isSpecial` is `NO`. Now I can probably accomplish something to this effect by adding multiple response descriptors, one for each of `GetObject?isSpecial=yes` and `GetObject?isSpecial=no`, but then I need to have a way of defining a special attribute mapping - I am not mapping attributes from key paths to key paths, but rather by request URL. How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using routing with path patterns and using the pattern meta data during mapping. I'm not sure you can pull out the queries individually so you may need to have a method on your managed object subclass which takes the meta data and extracts the parts you want to store.